# How to Handle Big JSON Response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I'm doing a simple iphone app, but the client sends me an 1.6mb JSON file, The client doesn't want to do any more in the backend, so I need an efficient way to handle this data, the data is going to be used later for filtering and searching inside the app.

What would you thing is the best way to handle this?

**Update**

This JSON in memory is around 4.85mb, do you guys think that is too much for an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Do you plan on adding the response data into SqlLite or are you planning on keeping it all in memory in your own structure?  If you keep it in SqlLite (CoreData), then you can read the file in chunks adding data to SqlLite as you go.

Comment: Core Data is not SQLite. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html

Comment: My first thought was to create a DB, but I asked the question because probably someone cames with a better idea

Comment: If your app uses too much memory, over 10 MB, then parts or all of the app are more likely to be shut down. Do you plan to parse this file just once? Or will you be given updated JSON data often enough that you expect the need to parse it frequently? The advantage of Core Data is that you can parse the JSON data into a local store, and then search only for the results you need. This lowers your app's overall memory profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse the JSON data into a [Core Data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902958/good-core-data-tutorial), using hashes to determine if a record is new or exists and needs updating. Use of threading for this step will make the app more responsive. You can then efficiently apply predicates (*i.e.*, filter and search) on the data store.

Also, some libraries/frameworks exist to handle the JSON to Core Data mapping such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). But keep in mind it's also pretty easy to do it yourself if you don't need a generalized solution.

Comment: Any special reason for using core data instead of a DB?

Comment: Core Data provides a lot of functionality for free, which you have to code by hand with a database engine. For example, if your data are structured with relationships, CD takes care of managing those relationships for you as you add, edit or remove instances of your data object. If you change your data model as you release a newer version of your app — for example, your JSON data suddenly includes new fields — Core Data provides a mechanism for clients to upgrade their data store, to support the new model, with less code.